# One tuple agains two properties

Tags: c#, processing-efficiency

I have some interesting question about program efficiency.
Which one of this two declarations would you prefer?

```
public int Health { get; set; }
public int Damage { get; set; }
```

or

```
public Tuple<int, int> Stats;
```

I'm working on something like Heartstone and I'm figuring out how to save Attack/Health values, is it good idea to use tuple for this?

Comment: What does that have to do with "efficiency"?  Why would you _not_ declare separate properties?

Comment: I prefer first one any time. Using Tuple for this is not good idea.

Comment: I would vote for the separate properties, if only because you can reference each by name. Tuple doesn't allow for naming the properties, so this could easily be confused. If anything, you could use a `Stats` class that has both of these properties in it. That said, this is primarily an opinion-based question. Always go for readability.

Comment: I don't know, just want to know if it's faster to use tuple before two properties

Comment: Okay, that's true, I'm going to use seperated properties, readability is really important, thank you guys!

Comment: Regarding performance, you won't notice a difference. It's two properties and doubtful you'll need to call them often enough to care - as a general rule, go for readability unless you identify a distinct need to speed something up.

Comment: If you use Tuple, you will have to remember that Health is the `Item1` property and that Damage is the `Item2` property. You will just obfuscate your code with no real benefit.

Comment: Is your program too slow? **Have you verified that it is too slow because you have two properties?** If the answer to either question is "no" then why are you asking this question?

Comment: using tuple would make it even slower because its another class containing two properties.... while you can have two properties directly.... also tuple values cant be changed...

Answer (score 2):

A tuple is a class so there isn't going to be any noticeable difference in the proposed code unless I'm mistaken.

The key would be readability. Tuples having generic Item names (e.g. Item1) might cause a hindrance down the road if you need to know exactly what those values in Stats mean.

So on that note, I personally would do a class for Stats with the two properties.

Slightly off-topic from the question but there is a usability difference. Tuples are immutable which means the Items don't have setters. Sorry if I am making too big of an assumption but in a game scenario you may want to modify those stats which you would not be able to do with a tuple.